# Changes at client when migrating WCF web api to asp.net core

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, wcf, grpc

I have a wcf service hosted at IIS and multiple clients are already calling it. Now we want to get rid of windows and move our web api to linux therefore we are going for asp.net core gRPC. Now my question is:
Do my clients need to make changes on their side when we shift towards asp.net core?

Comment: This needs to change the client, because WCF and gRpc serialization methods are different.

Comment: Kindly guide what changes they need to perform since the response will be same xml

Comment: For more information about migrating WCF solutions to gRPC you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/migrate-wcf-to-grpc